# Do IE CSS filters affect performance in other browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter

I'm wondering whether to put all CSS filters in a separate IE-only stylesheet, meaning an extra HTTP request, or just leave them in one big style sheet. Even though the filters are ignored by non-IE browsers, I imagine they would still have to be at least identified. Is there noticeable overhead for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, no. Because the filters do nothing in any other browser, the only performance hit is almost immeasurable in the amount of time it takes to load the line of CSS and figure out that it does nothing. There's no reason to worry about it.

If you're really concerned about it, you can put the filters in a separate IE specific CSS file and wrap the `<link>` element in a conditional IE statement.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a comment-style include of an IE specific stylesheet(s).  They would not even be loaded for non-IE browsers and load tie of all characters is probably the best saving here.  I wouldn't worry about and extra http call or two for version specific sylesheets, but as always that will depend on your actual site structure and content, e.g. stylesheet sizes.

e.g.
**IE 7 or over:**
`<!--[if gt IE 6]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->`

or

**IE 6 only:**
`<!--[if IE 6]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->`